# What was the original paper that showed a simulation of turing machines via circuits?

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines, circuits, simulation

It is a very standard construction in most complexity theory courses to turn a turing machine into a circuit. I thought this was due to Cook, but it looks like he did the reduction to SAT not through circuits and so now I am unsure. Is there a paper that originally established the well-known circuit simulation  that has remained state-of-the-art the last 50 or so years, or has it just been folklore?